# How to concatenate a string with variable in my case

Tags: sql, sql-server, filepath

I am trying to concatenate file path and folder name variable like below

```
Declare @FileName int

SET @FileName = 1

insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',  
'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\ExportData\'+ CAST(@FileName AS varchar(10))+'.xlsx;',  //Incorrect syntax near + expecting ',' or ';'
'SELECT top 100 ItemNo,Name FROM [Sheet1$]') select top 100 ItemNo,Name from product
```

Normally when I do concatenate with + operator, I am not getting any error as I defined like above. Only in this case I am getting an error

Comment: `OPENROWSET()` does not support expression or variable as input to the parameter, it must be string literal. One workaround is to generate the entire `OPENROWSET` query dynamically, use `exec()` or `sp_executesql` to execute the dynamic query

Comment: It sure would be nice if it did though!

Comment: The feedback is [under review](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/33713650-openrowset-remove-restriction-on-file-path-needing)

Comment: @Squirrel thanks for finding that. I voted it up

Comment: @Squirrel Could it be worth creating an answer that says your first comment and also suggests voting for it using that link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OPENROWSET()` does not support expression or variable as input to the parameter, it must be string literal.

One workaround is to generate the entire `OPENROWSET` query dynamically, use `exec()` or `sp_executesql`

This limitation has been feedback in [Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/33713650-openrowset-remove-restriction-on-file-path-needing)